# Modify Rake Task at test/runtime

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake

Consider the following

```
class Foo
  def bar
    1
  end
end
```

And then two rake tasks ...

```
task :something
  InvokeSomething(Foo.new)
end

task :test
  do_some_testing
end

def do_some_testing
   setup_test
   `rake something`
   check_if_it_did_everything_correctly
end
```

After executing `setup_test`, I want to modify the source for `class Foo` to `return 2` for method `bar`.

Ideas:

- Create a rake task that gets invoked before I define the rake task `something` and I modify the source code directly. So that `something` is defined with a different source code.
- Somehow modify the Rake task so that that particular method is overridden. At the very least I need a reference to the rake task during runtime.

Comment: This wheel was invented years ago: you should [`mock`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks) the original method to return `2`.

Comment: @mudasobwa notice that I invoke the rake task by shelling it out. I have no reference to it. I can't mock until I redesign the tests entirely.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this.

You can get the reference from `Rake::Task["something"]` during `do_some_testing` and re-define a method there.

But there is another even simpler way - which worked for me. Set the value in `bar` as an environment variable. And modify the environment variable when needed.